# How to write lambda output to JSON in s3

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have something in python 2.7 that works well when writing to CSV,  how can I add an output to json in a separate file in the same s3 bucket?

```
#boto3 library ec2 API describe addresses page
    #http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_addresses
    addresses = ec2con.describe_addresses().get('Addresses',[] )
    addresseslist = len(addresses)
    if addresseslist > 0:
        csv_file.write("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n"%('','','','',''))
        csv_file.write("%s,%s\n"%('EIPS INSTANCE',regname))
        csv_file.write("%s,%s,%s,%s\n"%('PublicIp','AllocationId','Domain','InstanceId'))
        csv_file.flush()
        for address in addresses:
            PublicIp=address['PublicIp']
            try:
                AllocationId=address['AllocationId']
            except:
                AllocationId="empty"
            Domain=address['Domain']
            if 'InstanceId' in address:
                instanceId=address['InstanceId']
            else:
                instanceId='empty'
            csv_file.write("%s,%s,%s,%s\n"%(PublicIp,AllocationId,Domain,instanceId))
            csv_file.flush()...

date_fmt = strftime("%Y_%m_%d", gmtime())
#Give your file path
filepath ='/tmp/AWS_Resources_' + date_fmt + '.csv'
#Save Inventory
s3.Object('s3BUCKETNAME', filename).put(Body=open(filepath, 'rb'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was helpful however,  I managed to get the json IP list by adding

```
 iplist = list()

 for address in addresses:
            PublicIp=address['PublicIp']
            iplist.append(PublicIp)


 s3.Object('S#BUCKETNAME', account_id + "_" + date_fmt).put(Body=json.dumps(iplist))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a similar function based on the one you already have, but first build a Python list of dictionaries like the following. Read more about [lists and dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) and [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) if needed. You can then create a string from the dictionary for writing to an S3 file.

Note that you have a lot of style issues with your Python code. Things like variable names, list length checks, etc. Please look through [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?) for style recommendations.

```
addresses_json = []
for address in addresses:
    # extract values as you already do

    # create dict
    addresses_json.append(dict(
        PublicIp=PublicIp,
        AllocationId=AllocationId,
        Domain=Domain,
        instanceId=instanceId
    ))

body = json.dumps(addresses)
filepath = '/tmp/AWS_Resources_' + date_fmt + '.json'

# use similar s3 calls to create a file for the JSON
```